# set dropdownlist selection to hardcoded aspx defined value

Tags: c#, asp.net, html-select

how do i set the dropdown selection to the option i hardcoded in the aspx page? "

i defined it like this:

```
 <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownListTug" runat="server" 
  DataSourceID="SqlDataSourceTugs"
  DataTextField="Tug_Name" DataValueField="Tug_ID" AutoPostBack="True"         
  AppendDataBoundItems="True"OnSelectedIndexChanged="ShowNewRateBtn">
 <asp:ListItem Value="0" Text="&lt;Select&gt;" Enabled="True" Selected="False"></asp:ListItem>
</asp:DropDownList>
```

I'm trying to reset in the codebehind by using either

```
       protected void NewTug_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        processTugs.Visible = true;
        tname.Visible = true;
        allButtons.Visible = true;

        pubvar.EnableAllControls(Page);
        //DropDownListTug.ClearSelection();
        //DropDownListTug.SelectedIndex = 0;
        //DropDownListTug.SelectedValue = "0";
        BtnNewRate.Visible = false;
        BtnDelete.Visible = false;
        BtnUpdate.Visible = false;
        BtnSave.Visible = false;
        BtnNewTugSave.Visible = true;
        BtnCancel.Visible = true;

    }
```

but its causing it to select the first index of the table and not the above index 0 i defined in the aspx page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding datasource and bind the drop down will remove the existing element. Add the element through `Insert` at index zero in code behind after binding.

```
DropDownListTug.DataSource = datatable;
DropDownListTug.DataBind(); 
DropDownListTug.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Add New", ""));
DropDownListTug.ClearSelection();
DropDownListTug.SelectedIndex = 0;
```

Comment: i dont want to add the element to my table. else i would have to repeat it for every single table where i want to do the same. is there no way to do it otherwise?

Comment: You are not adding element to datatable by this answer.

Comment: ok. at the .DataBind() its giving the error:

Both DataSource and DataSourceID are defined on 'DropDownListTug'.  Remove one definition. which do i remove?

Comment: Bind dropdown from code behind instead of giving DataSourceId

Comment: You bind the datasource to the drop down list in code-behind, that is usually your mypage.aspx.cs file. You can do it in Page_Load, or make your own methods for doing it when you need it. Just make sure to put it in if(!IsPostBack) { myBindingMethod() } unless you want it to refresh on every postback.

Comment: This could be good starting point to check how to bind dropdownlist from code behind http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/412998/bind-data-to-dropdownlist-with-csharp